# How long onhandleintent wait after stop service

Tags: android, service, intentservice

Suppose i have a service and in onHandleIntent some task is running and meanwhile i stopped the service and ondestroy() is called then how long will it stays in onHandleIntent.

Suppose i my code is like this...

boolean isRunning = true;

```
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

  // Suppose i don't false here bool.
   }

  protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onHandleIntent(intent);

   while(isRunning){
    // Some stuff are running here...
    }
  }
```

I know I should do false boolean in onDestroy() butI just want to know how long will it stay in onHandleIntent() evenif i don't make boolean to false.

Please give me some valuable views.

Comment: If you want a service that is running in an indefinite loop this way, an `IntentService` is not an appropriate choice IMHO. Use a regular `Service`. The point behind `IntentService` is for it to stop itself when `onHandleIntent()` ends, not to be stopped by some outside party.

Comment: @commonsWare: Means service will not be stopped untill it reach to end of onHandleIntent..it doesn't matter if I call for stop service. ..right??

Comment: As you said onHandleIntent stop itself when it reach to end but what will happen if I stop service and ondestroy calls then what will happen?? Actually my question was this..

Comment: That behavior is undefined. That is one of the reasons why I would not use an `IntentService` for your scenario, as I noted in my first comment. Use a regular `Service`, where you control the background thread and the behavior when the service is stopped by some other party via `stopService()`.